# Trouble with C# and Combobox not loading list

Tags: c#, list, combobox

I'm working on building a List using Combobox that when a Client is selected from the combo list, it loads a specific URL. Problem is the List is blank.
Below is the code, but I don't see what I'm missing but it could be simple oversight since this is the first time I'm building a Combobox like this.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<MyClient> clients;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        clients = new List<MyClient>();
        clients.Add(new MyClient { ClientName = "Client 1", UrlAddress = @"http://www.google.com" });
        BindBigClientsList();
    }

    private void BindBigClientsList()
    {
        BigClientsList.DataSource = clients;
        BigClientsList.DisplayMember = "ClientName";
        BigClientsList.ValueMember = "UrlAddress";
    }

    private void BigClientsList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyClient c = BigClientsList.SelectedItem as MyClient;
        if (c != null)
        {
            string url = c.ClientName;
            Process.Start(url);
        }
    }
}
class MyClient
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string UrlAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're creating: List<MyClient> clients And you're populating it, but beyond that you're not doing anything with it. You're later setting: BigClientsList.DataSource = ClientSize; But what is `ClientSize`?

Comment: call the BindBigClientsList function when in the form_load event

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. Not sure why I put " = ClientSize";. It should've just been " = clients";.

Comment: Still won't work, clients in the case of the code you've shown is a local variable and will no longer exist when you exit the constructor. Perhaps you're intending to initialize a member variable instead?

Comment: I believe so, but this is my first attempt at building a combobox this complex, so I know I'm goofed it somewhere. I'm a noob when it comes to C# so any direction will be appreciated.

Comment: I edit the code and pasted the new code above. Problem is that now I'm getting a Win32 Exception error for Process.Start(url), saying that the specified file does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor should look like this

```
public Form1() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
        List<MyClient> clients = new List<MyClient>(); 
        clients.Add(new MyClient { ClientName = "Client 1", UrlAddress = @"http://www.google.com" });
        foreach(MyClient client in clients)
        {
            BigClients.Items.Add(client);
        } 
    }
```

This adds two things:

- **Add the object to the ComboBox.** Without that, how is the item supposed to appear in the ComboBox?
- **Put the code after the InitializeComponent() statement.** Otherwise, when you try to add the MyClient object to the ComboBox, it will throw a NullReferenceException.

Comment: This answer looks like OK to me... I do not know why somebody downvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the last line: **DataBind**

```
private void BindBigClientsList()
{
    BigClientsList.DataSource = ClientSize;
    BigClientsList.DisplayMember = "ClientName";
    BigClientsList.ValueMember = "UrlAddress";
    BigClientsList.DataBind;
}
```